# Typescript React Component get return value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How can I get result from component class with this way?

this my how I called `ExampleSelectionComponent`, it shows me what I want to see but need to get `exampleSelectionId` value on this class.

```
public render() {
  const { exampleId  } = this.state;
  return(
    <div>
      <tr>
          <ExampleSelectionComponent id="ExampleSelection" 
           exampleSelectionId={exampleId} 
           tabId={this.props.tabId}/>
      </tr>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Can you please explain and maybe add a use-case instead

Comment: what do you mean by `need to get exampleSelectionId value on this class.`

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely have to pass down a method that updates the state of this parent component.

```js
class ParentComponent extends Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props:any){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            exampleId: 123,
        }
    }

    private setSelectionId(newId: number) {
        this.setState({exampleId: newId});
    }

    public render() {
        const {exampleId} = this.state.exampleId;
        return (
            <div>
                <tr>
                    <ExampleSelectionComponent id="ExampleSelection"
                                               updateSelectionId={this.setSelectionId}
                                               tabId={this.props.tabId} />
                </tr>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Then from within your `ExampleSelectionComponent` call updateSelectionId when you want to change it in the parent.

Comment: Thank you so much for answer and I asked my question again.
I put my question again same like answer post.

Comment: My answer would still work. You need to pass a `method` that updates `Example` down as a prop, not set the state in the child element. The two states are not linked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you are right, I need to explain a bit more,
I have two .tsx (Example and ExampleSelectionComponent). I'm calling my ExampleSelectionComponent.tsx from Example.tsx.

ExampleSelectionComponent.tsx has a TextField and I can change it. when I change it, I'm updating state value in it (value).

That's what I want: If I changed textfield value in ExampleSelectionComponent.tsx on browser and then I clicked DefaultButton in Example.tsx. its gonna make work getExampleSelectionComponentTextFieldValue() and I wanna put ExampleSelectionComponent TextField value there.

Im adding two pictures from classes at down;

[Example.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNzTx.jpg)

[ExampleSelectionComponent.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi6jx.jpg)